# SQL select unique table rows across all columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that has the following results as shown below

```
total_passengers origin_city_name  dest_city_name   year
----------------------------------------------------------------
2926589          New York          Chicago          2009
2926589          Chicago           New York         2009
2876933          Los Angeles       San Francisco    2009
2876933          San Francisco     Los Angeles      2009
```

How to remove the redundant rows - 2 & 4.

Thanks

Comment: `select total_passengers, origin_city_name, Dest_city_name, year
from YourTable a
where not exists (select 1 
                   from YourTable b
                  where b.total_passengers = a.total_passengers)
                        `

Comment: @Sabthosh Define 'redundant'. As you can see from the comments you have not given enough information, e.g. whether the order is important, there will always be pairs, etc.

Comment: @JonDoggen New york to Chicago is one route with total passengers as 2926589 in 2009. The row chicago to New York also mentions the same. One of the rows needs to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care if origin and source might be swapped when there's no 2nd row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  total_passengers,
  CASE WHEN origin_city_name > dest_city_name 
       THEN dest_city_name 
       ELSE origin_city_name
  END,
  CASE WHEN origin_city_name < dest_city_name 
       THEN dest_city_name
       ELSE origin_city_name
  END,
  year
FROM tab
;
```

Comment: it ain't pretty, but it sure gets the job done! +1

Answer (score 1):

Add a WHERE clause to your query, so you don't get reverse origin-destination records:

```
WHERE origin_city_name < dest_city_name
```

Comment: you will loose half of the results and count will return invalid numbers

Comment: @StanislavL - how can you know that without knowing OP's original query? If the sample data shown by OP is stored in a plain table, then my suggestion would work just fine. Loosing half the results is exactly what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: in general your idea is right. I would UNION ALL 2 queries WHERE origin_city_name < dest_city_name and WHERE origin_city_name > dest_city_name swapping city names.

Comment: This would only work if you could guarantee that there is exactly twice as much data as you need. If there are any city pairs that only appear once, you may not get them included in the results, depending on the names.

Comment: @ninesided you're absolutely right, but OP is not giving us much information to work with here...

Comment: the table result is aggregated on a years data (rowcount = 3 million).  It indicates total passengers on a route A to B.  So I want to remove  the reverse route B to A. There are other routes as well B-> X, X->xx using the above condition will not return all the rows which I need.

Answer (score 0):

In a slight variation on [dnoeth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550168/1030):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
total_passengers, 
LEAST(origin_city_name, dest_city_name) AS origin_city_name,
GREATEST(origin_city_name, dest_city_name) AS dest_city_name,
year
FROM yourtable;
```

and [here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6d13c/1/0).

Comment: least() and greatest() are not supported in Amazon redshift, sorry I didn't mention the db used earlier.

Comment: That would have been useful information! I've added it to the tag list above.

Comment: The most elegant solution, not supported by the "Business Intelligence" platform. So sad. Sigh.